# Can I submit Job offer letter as proof of employment?

Tags: schengen-visas

I am planning to apply for Schengen Visa for Italy from UK. I have resigned from my current job. I will be switching jobs and have a Job Offer letter. So should the below documents suffice as an employment proof:-
1. 3 months payslip from previous job
2. Job offer letter for new job.

Thanks in advance for your guidance!

Comment: Please could you edit the question to include your citizenship?

Answer (score 4):

**A job offer is not the same as a job.**

And a job offer letter is proof only that you have a job offer, not a job. A job offer is much less valuable in proving ties to your home country because you might have declined it, and even if you accept it you can quit it with few consequences. A job offer which you have not accepted will be virtually valueless for the visa application.

If you have accepted the job, then your new employer should be able to provide you with a letter stating that you are actually employed, your start date, salary etc., as well as contact information for the employer. Do this. A recent job is more valuable than a job offer, but less valuable than a job you have held for a long time, because you can quit it with fewer consequences, so be prepared for the letter to carry much less weight than proof of a job you have held for a long time. The start date they show should be after your planned return from the trip, or it should indicate that they have given you leave for the trip.

You should still provide the payslips from your previous job because they speak to your general financial situation.

If you are unsure of your chances of success with the visa it might be advisable to delay your trip until you have been in the new job several months to improve your chances.